# How to detect resizeable window state in pygame and de-maximize it in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, pygame

I have an application built in python with use of pygame that initially displays a login screen at a set size which is not RESIZABLE and then when user logs into the game the saved settings are being used to transform the window size. The window is turned into RESIZABLE after login. If user logs out the window is changed back to the initial size without RESIZABLE flag. Everything is OK as long as the user logs out from normal window, but when user hits the maximize button and then logs out in some distros the window still stays maximized and the login screen is being painted in a top left corner of the window.

And here comes the question, is there a way of detecting whether the window has been maximized so I can de-maximize it before sizing down?

I couldn't find anything that would help me with this in the pygame docs or anywhere online. I have found a way of getting a "handle" to the window by using:

```
pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window']
```

but not sure where to take it from here.

The way I set the sizes:

```
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480)) #login screen
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(user_saved_size, pygame.RESIZABLE) #game screen
```

Answer (score 2):

`get_wm_info()['wmwindow']` gives you windowID in Windows Manager (X.org) but it is "outside" of PyGame. Maybe with python library `Xlib` you could do something.

---

**EDIT:**

I tried example in [Setting the window dimensions of a running application](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6000) to change terminal size and it works but it don't change PyGame window size. I tried xlib to get PyGame window caption and it works but I could not set PyGame window caption.It seems PyGame doesn't respect new caption.

I use this code to test PyGame window caption - it can get caption but it can't set caption.

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import Xlib
import Xlib.display

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1500, 300

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32)

print "wm_info:", pygame.display.get_wm_info()
print "  window:", pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window']
print "fswindow:", pygame.display.get_wm_info()['fswindow']
print "wmwindow:", pygame.display.get_wm_info()['fswindow']

display = Xlib.display.Display()
root = display.screen().root

#windowID = root.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType).value[0]
#print "Xlib windowID:", windowID
#window = display.create_resource_object('window', windowID)

window = display.create_resource_object('window', pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window'])
window.configure(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
print "Xlib   window get_wm_name():", window.get_wm_name()

window = display.create_resource_object('window', pygame.display.get_wm_info()['fswindow'])
window.configure(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
print "Xlib fswindow get_wm_name():", window.get_wm_name()

window = display.create_resource_object('window', pygame.display.get_wm_info()['wmwindow'])
window.configure(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
print "Xlib wmwindow get_wm_name():", window.get_wm_name()

print

print "Xlib wmwindow set_wm_name(hello world of xlib)"
window.set_wm_name("hello world of xlib")
display.sync()

print "Xlib wmwindow get_wm_name():", window.get_wm_name()


# --------------

fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
RUNNING = True
while RUNNING:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            RUNNING = False

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                RUNNING = False

    fpsClock.tick(25)

# --------------

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I use this code to change window size - it works in terminal and DreamPie (python shell):

```
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/setting-the-window-dimensions-of-a-running-application

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1500, 300
import Xlib
import Xlib.display

display = Xlib.display.Display()
root = display.screen().root
windowID = root.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType).value[0]
window = display.create_resource_object('window', windowID)
window.configure(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
display.sync()

#windowIDs = root.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_CLIENT_LIST'), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType).value
#for windowID in windowIDs:
#   window = display.create_resource_object('window', windowID)
#   name = window.get_wm_name() # Title
#   pid = window.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_PID'), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType) # PID
```

Comment: Thanks furas for your answer. At least I know I'm asking for "impossible" in pygame. I guess I'll go for a different solution - the window will be resized to the saved size after login, but I'll keep the same size after logout and center the login panel - it doesn't really look bad.
Thanks.